# Using the output of a piped sed for the replacement value of a second sed

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, sed, npm

I am trying to get the version of a npm package, and use it to replace the value in another file. Specifically, I want to get the `package.json` version and use that to replace the wordpress `style.css` version.

I'm able to successfully get the version number using `npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g'`, but I've tried every variation to get it to put in the output of that into the `s` of another piped `sed`. (I've tried -e -r -i and all combinations therein, I've tried `$1`, `\1`, `${echo $1}`, etc...)

`npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g' | sed "s/1.0.0/$1/g" dist/style.css` (in the final version I would use -i in the second sed)

In the style.css file, I want to replace `1.0.0` with the output of `npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g'`

Comment: *'echo | sed file'* can't work, you cannot process both inputs together. either process pipe or file. what is `$1` and how did you set value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pipe variables to sed. It doesn't matter *how* you're writing the back-reference – there is literally no *feature* in sed that would actually produce the back-reference in the way that you're trying to do.

(sed only uses stdin to take the actual input text, and if you're specifying a file to edit (style.css), then stdin is not being used at all.)

When using `$` inside a double-quoted string, however, it's not expanded by sed itself – it's expanded by your shell, well before sed runs. For back-references that's not good (one would use `\$` to cause an actual $ to be passed to the command); but in your case, that's exactly the shell feature you need.

Instead of trying to connect both with a pipe (the 2nd sed will not accept anything piped into it), use two separate pipelines and the shell's variable substitutions:

1. Store the result from npm in a shell variable using `$(command)` or `` `command` ``:

   ```
   version=$(npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g')
   ```

   (It would be slightly more "technically correct" to use `jq -r .` for unquoting npm's JSON output, but this is just a version string, so your sed will be good enough.)
2. Include the variable as part of the sed command:

   ```
   sed -i "s/1\.0\.0/$version/g" dist/style.css
   ```

   Beware that this is expanded literally, e.g. if the version was `4.2beta`, then the actual command that'll be run is `sed -i "s/1\.0\.0/4.2beta/g"` – this is important if sed's `/` separator may occur inside the variable. (In your case, it hopefully won't.)
3. It's possible to merge both steps, e.g. `sed -i "s/old/$(npm get | sed)/g" file`, but that soon becomes nigh-unreadable, so don't do that.
4. If you have node.js anyway, think about writing a node.js script that does the editing instead of using fragile shell tools.

Comment: *printf -v version '%q' "$(npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g')"* should escape all regex characters

Comment: Not all of them; e.g. it wouldn't escape `.`, and depending on which regex syntax you're using, it would _needlessly_ escape some of them (e.g. in BRE, plain `(` is not special, but escaped `\(` actually is). In this case though that's not needed because the variable is only used as replacement string, not as the match regex, so only backreferences (`&` and backslash) and the sed command separator (in this case `/`) need escaping.

Comment: Thank you for the information. While I totally agree with your #3 (I very much dislike nested code that is difficult to parse, especially regex...it's the reason I write in Typescript), it is the solution I ended up using. The reason being is that I needed a one-liner to put into an npm script that could get run automatically on build. I suppose writing a js file that could be run would have also worked, but that (as well as `jq`) is an added dependency. `sed -i "s/1.0.0/$(npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g')/g" dist/style.css` (EDIT: the versioning for this project is always going to be #.#.#)